# Git command to get release notes?

Tags: git

I want to get tag release note, is it possible ?

I can get remote tags with :

```
git ls-remote --tags https://my git repo
```

But I want the release notes text attached to them?

Answer (score 2):

Using git you can get a list of commit messages by cloning the repo and running

```
git log TAG1..TAG2 --oneline --decorate
```

to get an output like this

```
55bbbdc (tag: 0.0.2) 0.0.2
254aa66 fix(eslint-plugin): expose new rules and use type guards (#8)
23d5a6f feat(eslint-plugin): prefer onpush component cd (#7)
```

While it's can be convenient for personal use, this is rarely a good format for sharing with others. To get better results use libraries like [github-changelog-generator](https://github.com/github-changelog-generator/github-changelog-generator) (Ruby, Github only) or [auto-changelog](https://github.com/CookPete/auto-changelog) (Node.js).

I've built a list of [release notes best practices](https://co-pilot.dev/changelog) to take them to the next level. It requires being mindful about formatting, writing and annotating commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to do that with git cli but you can use `gh` ([github cli](https://cli.github.com/)) and that gives you release notes from the release page. `gh release view`